# Query error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to alternate names by querying to view in sql server. The query is as follows,

```
select 
    CalendarDate, year, month, day, date, hour,
    AVG_VAL, Sum_Val, DVCPORTmc1_Port_No, DVCm_Location,
    case 
       when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_1'
         then 'Current A/C 1'
         else case 
                 when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_2'
                   then 'Current A/C 2' 
                   else case 
                          when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Water' 
                          then 'Water' 
                        end         
              end          
        as DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name  
from 
    [REPORT_Device_Dt_Calendar_YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR]
where 
    DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name like 'mesh-Cu_%' or
where DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name like 'mesh-Water'
order by 
    [year], [month] desc, convert(int, [day]) asc
```

Which gives the error,

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

What is wrong in query?

Comment: one of the `end`s before  `as  DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name` are redundant

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you could simplify your `CASE` statement:

```
case 
   when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_1'
      then 'Current A/C 1'
   when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_2'
      then 'Current A/C 2' 
   when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Water' 
      then 'Water' 
end as DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name
```

No need for all those nested `CASE` statements...

Secondly: if you want to have multiple criteria in your `WHERE` clause, don't repeat the `WHERE` keyword - use this instead (just use the `OR` or `AND` keyword):

```
WHERE
    DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name LIKE 'mesh-Cu_%' 
    OR
    DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name LIKE 'mesh-Water'
```

Comment: Or could simplify it even further with `case DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name...`  as all conditions check the same column.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy you need to learn the syntax for programming basics with SQL concepts. Use the below code for the time being:

```
select 
    CalendarDate, year, month, day, date, hour,
    AVG_VAL, Sum_Val, DVCPORTmc1_Port_No, DVCm_Location,
    case 
       when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_1'
            then 'Current A/C 1'
       when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Cu_2'
            then 'Current A/C 2' 
       when DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name = 'mesh-Water' 
            then 'Water' 
    end as DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name  
from 
    [REPORT_Device_Dt_Calendar_YEAR_MONTH_DAY_HOUR]
where 
    DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name like 'mesh-Cu_%' or
    DVCPORTmc1_SENSOR_Program_name like 'mesh-Water'
order by 
    [year], [month] desc, convert(int, [day]) asc
```